# Javascript failing compare dates

Tags: javascript, date, compare, getdate

im tryng to create a system that open and close rounds in some date and time for users to play.
The problem is that javascript is not beeing precise, some times its faling to make the change in the correct time, and just change 1 minute later.

Maybe the problem is becouse I am geting de original date in UTC and converting before compare this date with the actual date and time...

I try compare using >=, just <, using .getTime(), but the problem is the same, javascript dont detect when the times are equal, the comparing only works 1 minute later, when one date is minor or greater than other.

This is the last code:

```js
round_ended = new Date(round.ended + 'Z');
var date = new Date();

if (date.getTime() >= round_ended.getTime()) {
 round.phase = "closed";
}
```

As I say, i have tried, with no success, other variations like this:

```js
round_ended = new Date(round.ended + 'Z');
var date = new Date();

if (!(date < round_ended)) {
 round.phase = "closed";
}
```

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

What if you compare date ISO Strings.

```
if (!(date.toISOString() < round_ended.toISOString())) {
    round.phase = "closed";
}
```

The ISO format is fixed : `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion, but this is not working too... I guess is some problem with miliseconds, but i found a solution and I will post in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I still dont no exactly the problem, but i guess is the miliseconds.
So, i found a solution based on this guess.

I compare the difference of the two values and check if it is smaller than 1000:

```js
var time = round_ended - date;

if (time < 1000) {
  round.phase = "closed";
}
```

Now it work's fine.

Thanks for the help.